# error while installing robot framework on ironpython

Tags: testing, robotframework, ironpython

I'm becoming mad about installing robotframework on IronPython in a Windows machine. Please someone could take a look on this.

I have installed IronPython 2.7.7, added the path system variable for both main and Scripts folder, also I installed the elementtree-1.2.7-20070827-preview.zip as it looks that the library that comes with IronPython is "broken" (this info and instruction comes from IronPython site).

Then I run the

```
    ipy -X:Frames -m ensurepip
```

to be able to use pip.

Everything should be ready now to get the robotframework installed by:

```
    ipy -X:Frames -m pip install robotframework
```

The package starts getting downloaded until here:

```
  Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\extern\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\extern\__init__.py", line 42, in load_module
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\six.py", line 701, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\six.py", line 692, in exec_
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_getframe'

----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\***\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-vnlada\robotframework\
```

I tried another workaround just downloading the robotframework source, uncompressing and placing it in my program folders. From the RF folder I tried to run:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\ipy.exe" setup.py install
```

and again same error:

```
     File "setup.py", line 11, in <module>
       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-                  packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\extern\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\extern\__init__.py", line 42, in load_module
       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\six.py", line 701, in <module>
       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\six.py", line 692, in exec_
     AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_getframe'
```

In this website this guy solves the issue using this last workaround, however it didnt work for me.
http://it-kosmopolit.de/blog/2015/08/31/install-robot-framework-with-ironpython-on-windows/

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you try with previous ironpython versions? why can't you use CPython?

Comment: I want to test .NET SDK. For what I was reading the correct way to test from the  framework would be to run it on ironpython. I tried a 2.7 version as well with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolve it, however I dont intend to say is the way to resolve it.

There are installers .exe of Robot Framework for Windows but they are not intended to be on IronPython, but Python. Keeping in mind that I already got the IronPython folder, what I did is:

- install Python
- downloand and install the RF installer .exe file from here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/robotframework/2.8.5
- install it pointing to the Python directory (it doesnt recognize the IronPython folder)
- Simply added the ipy.exe from my IronPython folder to the PATH variable.

Surprisingly it worked with no more headache, I have now Robot Framework on IronPython.